# How do I auto update with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example consider a single input tag. If I were to not focus I want to be given this error

```
email: abcd         - ERROR: Please enter a valid email address
```

How I am trying to do this

html file:

```
<body>


   <form id="form1">



      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /> <br />


   </form>

   <script>
       validator().validateForm1("#form1")
      
   </script>

</body>
```

js file:

```
function validator() {

    const self = {}

    

    self.validateForm1 = function (form) {
        elem = document.querySelector(form)
        
    }
```

As you can see I am trying to do it in this manner where I run a function and then all the errors will start showing. Currently I am lost on how to get the error to show in real time after I unfocus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<body>
   <form id="form1">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /> <br />
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [keyup  event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) or [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event).

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /> <br />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /> <br />
  </form>
  <script>
    function validator() {
      const self = {};
 
      self.validateForm1 = function () {
        const email = document.getElementById("email");
        email.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
          console.log(`this function trigger after add one char. (${this.value})`);
        });
        
        email.addEventListener("blur", function(event){
          console.log(`this function trigger after leave the input. (${this.value})`);
        });
      };
 
      return self;
    }
    validator().validateForm1();
  </script>
</body>
```